# Custom validation rule - for unique value

Tags: validation-rule, custom-metadata

I'm using Custom Metadata Types and writing validation rule to find if this combination has uniqueness if it's (meaning its a duplicates) then throw an error

here is what I was able to do but I'm stuck in one silly error.

> Error: Syntax error. Missing '='

```
AND(
NOT(ISNEW() && ISBLANK(Select_Type__c) && ISBLANK(Complete__Order__c) && ISBLANK(Employee__r.DeveloperName)),
OR(
    NOT(ISNEW()) && ISCHANGED(Select_Type__c),
    NOT(ISNEW()) && ISCHANGED(Complete__Order__c),
    NOT(ISNEW()) && ISCHANGED(Employee__r.DeveloperName),
    ISNEW()
),
NOT(
    ISBLANK(Select_Type__c) &&
    ISBLANK(Complete__Order__c) &&
    ISBLANK(Employee__r.DeveloperName)
),
ISNEW() || 
NOT(
    EXISTS(
        [SELECT Select_Type__c, Complete__Order__c ,  Employee__r.DeveloperName FROM Employer__mdt WHERE Select_Type__c =: Select_Type__c AND Complete__Order__c =: Complete__Order__c AND Employee__r.DeveloperName  =:  Employee__r.DeveloperName
LIMIT 1]
    )
)
)
```

Comment: or is there any other way to find the uniqueness combining of those three fields?

Comment: where is the `EXISTS` function documented?

Comment: Yes exactly there is no `EXISTS` function in salesforce https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_parent.htm&type=5, or is this part of some new release not documented still?

Comment: Why is there a query inside of this validation rule? Have I just been missing something?

Comment: You cannot use SOQL queries in validation rules. This sort of thing would typically be done in a trigger. Unfortunately, triggers cannot be created for Custom Metadata Types. The best you can do is complain about "duplicates" at runtime and either disable functionality that uses the CMT records (e.g. throw exception) or ignore duplicates but log the issue in a way that can be found by admins - e.g. create a Salesforce Notification about it.